# Django: Nginx with wsgi or uwsgi

Tags: nginx, monitoring, django

Which one has better performance, stability? Which monitoring tool should also be the best choice ? Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

From [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739810/wsgi-vs-uwsgi-with-nginx) (the second link when you google wsgi vs uwsgi(!)):

Ok, guys this is confusion because of lack of detail from several sources, and naming of these protocols, and what WSGI actually is.

Summary:

1. uwsgi **IS** a protocol not a server.  This is used to communicate with with web servers for load balancing to take advantage of extra features that pure http load balancing does not provide.  So far Nginx and Cherokee have implemented this protocol.
2. uWSGI is a server, one of the protocols it implements is WSGI.  WSGI is a Python specification.  There are several implementations of the WSGI specification and it's intended to be used for more then just application servers/web servers, but there are quite a few WSGI application servers (ie. CherryPy, which also happens to have a production ready WSGI compliant web server, if you weren't confused enough already!).
3. Comparing uwsgi to WSGI is comparing oranges to apples.

Comment: 3: Unless he is referring to the wsgi module for nginx.